# exFat on GT-9082

Tags: samsung-galaxy-grand, exfat

Is it possible to use a sdcard with the `exFat` on the Galaxy Grand Duos GT-I9082 ? Is it possible without a custom ROM ?

I am running Jellybean 4.2.2 on the stock ROM. I can upgrade to kikat on a non-stock ROM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you upgrade to KitKat ( that's the minimum Android version that supports exfat as explained here [Since which Android version is exFat supported?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/163197/131553) )

Your phone supports SDXC as listed [here](https://androidforums.com/threads/list-of-phones-that-work-with-128gb-microsdxc-card-by-sandisk.832403/) ( presumably on KitKat or higher )

SDXC is backward compatible to exfat as mentioned [here](http://www.androidauthority.com/high-capacity-microsd-cards-android-gary-explains-690710/) so it should support, unless there is something I am missing

You can also use this app [exfat checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wikimediacom.exFAT) to verify if your current configuration supports exfat

Comment: @+1 for exfat checker.