# moving apps to sd card is prevented by Huawei EmUI 3.1?

Tags: applications, sd-card, 5.1-lollipop

I wanted to ask you a question. why can not I move the apps on my sd card? my phone is a huawei cun-L21, android 5.1. the option is shown, but it is disabled. because? while, with another sd card, I can move the apps. do I have to format the card in a particular way?

Comment: Yes Fat32 should always would xfat will work on newer devices if the OEM enabled it.  https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/163197/since-which-android-version-is-exfat-supported

Comment: I used the "delete all data" function. Is this a formatting of the sd card? if so, in which filesystem?

Comment: Hmm I don't understand your question.  Yes the OS formatting should work.  Some cards can be to large sometimes...

Comment: what's the problem? too large?

Comment: Yes or the card is broken most likely

Comment: Format on PC use FAT32 (or exFAT ) and try

Comment: the reason why I can not move the app is only due to bad formatting?

Comment: @beeshyams does not work