# Approaches to support exFat on AOSP Android 10+ where it isnt native

Tags: file-system, mount, partitions, magisk, xposed-framework

Just found out that my AOSP Android does not support `exFat`. Any thoughts about getting exFat support  added.  I read about this [plugin](https://www.paragon-software.com/free/exfat-ntfs-fat32-hfs-android/) that will work  only for `USB-OTG` not for memory card - lest I will be forced to go `VFAT` with the 4gb limitation.I have seen some discussion on stack regarding this but no solution.
--How do I compile exFat support in Kernel
-- 
 -- If my /proc/mounts list `ext4`  does it mean if I format this to ext4 it will auto mount it or 1st partition of SD card unless `vfat` will not auto mount

 Alternatively how can I adopt [this](https://github.com/Magisk-Modules-Repo/vold-posix#readme)  `posix-vold` project to my ROM .  I modified the install script & removed the checks ( for Oreo ,Arm64 etc )  and installed it via `magisk` and it get stuck at this point

```
Compressing Ramdisk to fit in partition.....insufficient partition size ...installation failed
```

`/proc/filesystems` looks like this :

```
     # cat /proc/filesystems
nodev   sysfs
nodev   rootfs
nodev   ramfs
nodev   bdev
nodev   proc
nodev   cpuset
nodev   cgroup
nodev   cgroup2
nodev   tmpfs
nodev   configfs
nodev   debugfs
nodev   tracefs
nodev   sockfs
nodev   dax
nodev   bpf
nodev   pipefs
nodev   devpts
    ext3
    ext2
    ext4
    vfat
    msdos
    iso9660
nodev   sdcardfs
    fuseblk
nodev   fuse
nodev   fusectl
nodev   overlay
nodev   pstore
nodev   selinuxfs
nodev   functionfs
```

I am looking for something that will work. How about an `X-posed mod` any out there ?

Comment: Related: [Since which Android version is exFat supported?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/223592/218526) and [How to bind mount a folder inside /sdcard with correct permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217936/218526) and [How to create and use multiple partitions on external SD card with different filesystems?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220042/218526)

Comment: guess the *Known issue* section applies to all solutions. maybe check post from [Ziona](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3881473) (at least NTFS, untested)

Comment: ziona did not work I will post my debug log there

Comment: seems you must build your own kernel first

Comment: how "easy" is that..if easy enough remember that ota prob. ? wanna inc that as well. Surprised ... how in the world did Android dev think of `iso9660` aka optical disk support and forgot `exFat / NTFS`

Comment: it's not easy, but possible. probably hardest step is find kernel source code https://www.xda-developers.com/micromax-in-note-1-in-1b-bootloader-unlock-guide-kernel-source-code